# Asp.Net FormsAuth cookie not persisting

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-membership

I am having an issue with cookies not being persisted across browser sessions. If I close and reopen the  browser, the cookie is not passed along to the server on the next request.

This is how I create the cookie when the user signs in:

```
var ticket = new FormsAuthenticationTicket(
    1 /*version*/,
    user.Id,
    now,
    now.Add(ExpirationTimeSpan), /* ExpirationTimeSpan = TimeSpan.FromHours(6) */
    true /*createPersistentCookie*/,
    userData,
    FormsAuthentication.FormsCookiePath);

var encryptedTicket = FormsAuthentication.Encrypt(ticket);

var cookie = new HttpCookie(FormsAuthentication.FormsCookieName, encryptedTicket)
                    {
                        HttpOnly = true,
                        Secure = FormsAuthentication.RequireSSL,
                        Path = FormsAuthentication.FormsCookiePath
                    };
if (FormsAuthentication.CookieDomain != null)
{
    cookie.Domain = FormsAuthentication.CookieDomain;
}

var httpContext = this.contextAccessor.Current();
httpContext.Response.Cookies.Add(cookie);
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to set the expiration of the HttpCookie like so....

```
var cookie = new HttpCookie(FormsAuthentication.FormsCookieName, encryptedTicket)
        {
            HttpOnly = true,
            Secure = FormsAuthentication.RequireSSL,
            Path = FormsAuthentication.FormsCookiePath,
            Expires=  = DateTime.UtcNow.AddHours(6);
        };
```